# Apply a function to a nested list grouped by stream

Tags: java

There is a list of objects for the following class:

```
class A {
   String firstName;
   String lastName;
   //.....
}
```

There is also a method that takes in three parameters:

```
List<B> someMethod(String firstName, String lastName, List<A> l);
```

I want to group this list based on `firstName` and `lastName` and then apply this method to the items in the list of items that have `firstName` and `lastName`

I tried the following:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<B>>> groupedItems = l.stream()
     .collect(groupingBy(A::getFirstName, groupingBy(A::getLastName)));

List<B> result = groupedItems.keySet().stream()
     .map(firstName -> groupedItems.get(firstName).keySet().stream()
             .map(lastName -> someMethod(firstName, lastName, groupedItems.get(firstName).get(lastName))
             .collect(Collectors.toList()))
     .flatMap(Collection::stream)
     .collect(Collectors::toList);
```

Is there a way to do this in one shot instead of the way it is now?

Comment: you made it with groupedItems right?

Comment: You can do that using `Collectors.collectingAndThen()` (it does work with your code), but the code becomes close to unreadable...

Comment: What is `B`? You didn't provide that `class`.

Comment: @GhostCat I've posted the answer - let me know how you find the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `collectingAndThen`, but this, in my opinion, is far less readable.

```
List<B> result = l.stream().collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
    groupingBy(A::getFirstName, groupingBy(A::getLastName)),
    groupedItems -> groupedItems.keySet().stream()
            .flatMap(firstName -> 
                groupedItems.get(firstName)
                    .keySet()
                    .stream()
                    .map(lastName -> 
                        someMethod(
                                firstName, 
                                lastName, 
                                groupedItems.get(firstName).get(lastName)
                        )
                    )
            )
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(toList())));
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to somehow access the keys `firstName` and `lastName` and the resulting list from grouping the items based on them? 
`......someStreamFunction( (firstName, lastName, list) -> { .....}).....`

Comment: I see `nonstatic method cannot be referenced from static context` for the second flatMap.

Answer (score 0):

What about just iterate over gien `List<A>` and cache calculated results of `Lit<B>` for every unique `fileName + lastName`. It takes **O(n)** time and **O(n)** space.

```
public class Foo {

    private final Map<String, List<B>> map = new HashMap<>();

    public List<B> someMethod(String firstName, String lastName, List<A> as) {
        return map.compute(firstName + '|' + lastName, (key, bs) -> {
            if (bs == null) {
                // create List<B> based on given List<A>
                bs = Collections.emptyList();
            }
            return bs;
        });

    }

}
```